# how to force TbToggleColumn to use validation rules?

Tags: validation, gridview, yii, toggle, yii-booster

I'm using **TbExtendedGridView** from Yii Booster.
My 'status' column is defined as **TbToggleColumn**.

```
array(
        'name'=>'status',
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbToggleColumn',
        'toggleAction' => 'Artykul/toggle'
        ),
```

In my model I have a validation rule that prevents changing the value of 'status' unless some conditions are met. The validation works fine in create / update scenarios BUT it *doesn't work* - i.e. the condition is not checked - if I click to toggle 'status' in the gridview.

Any idea about how to force TbToggleColumn to use the **validation** rules defined in the model?

--- edit -

I have now changed in TbToggleAction shipped with Yii Booster:

> $success = $model->save(false, array($attribute));

to

> $success = $model->save(**true**, array($attribute));

Comment: when it is not working? You said it's working in create/update. Then what else remaining?

Comment: it's not working in 'toggle' Action. I have now changed in TbToggleAction (shipped with Yii Booster): 


    $success = $model->save(false, array($attribute));
to
    $success = $model->save(true, array($attribute));

Comment: So is it working now? confirm..